# stdout doesn't flush on Windows command prompt but works on OSX and Linux

Tags: python, linux, macos, cmd

I have written a piece of cake that displays progress it works as expected on OSX and Linux shell. Today I tested on Windows it didn't flush the last dumped text from shell.

```
done = int(50 * progress / int(file_size))
percentDone = int(progress) * 100. / file_size
speed = sizeof(progress//(clock() - start))
bar = '=' * done
die = ' ' * (50-done)
stdout.write("\r[%s%s][%3.2f%%] %s of %s at %s/s   " % (bar, die, percentDone, sizeof(progress), sizeof(file_size), speed))
stdout.flush()
```

The above code is from [where I am contributing here](https://github.com/sanfx/pytube/blob/print_status_flush/pytube/utils.py)

It works like charm on OSX:
[image]

But in case of each progress is dumped onto next line, leaving the previous line.

How can I achieve the functionality of `stdout.flush()` on Windows too ?

Comment: don't have a win for test, but try with „\b” (backtab, usualy 4 chars); maybe win console interpret „\r” as return car.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to use "\r"? If there's only one line that changes, it could be your solution.
It works like that:

```
>>> print("Hello\rP")
<<< Pello
```

Comment: thats it , i used it like this and it worked :` "\r  [%s%s][%3.2f%%] %s at %s/s\r " `